# PySide6: Incrustar sub-ventana dentro de una ventana principal

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica, pyqt5, frontend, pyside

Estoy intentando hacer una ventana principal simple con un fondo, una barra de menú y una barra de estado y que al seleccionar desde la barra de menú alguna aplicación, ésta se abra en una nueva sub-ventana modal pero que quede dentro de la ventana principal.

En un principio se me ocurrió hacer un stacked layout pero me parece que por un lado sería un malgasto de recursos ya que al ir abriendo aplicaciones, éstas quedarían "abiertas" (no se si hay una forma de "matar" un layout), y por otro lado sería mas código ya que debería bloquear/modificar la barra de menú cuando se muestra un índice distinto a 0 para que no puedan "abrirse" otras mientras está otra "abierta".

Luego intenté con creación de ventanas de clase QDialog, de ésta manera consigo que se abran y se cierren y que sólo admita el uso de una a la vez, sin embargo no me parece muy estético. Si bien, cuando la ventana principal está maximizada, logré que se abra la sub-ventana con el tamaño y la posición deseada, no es lo mismo al estar de tamaño menor. Quise tratar de hacer el cálculo para que su tamaño y posición sea relativa a la principal pero luego de mucha investigación no lo puede lograr.

Luego de estas dos opciones me encontré con la existencia de QMdiArea, sin embargo, por más que busqué no logré terminar de entender su funcionamiento y como ponerla en práctica.

Les dejo unas capturas de un sistema de gestión hecho en Java que suelo utilizar en mi trabajo para que se den una idea de lo que quiero lograr:

`Ventana "normal":`
Al abrir cualquier app desde la barra de menú se abre de la siguiente manera
[image: Ventana "normal"]

`Ventana al cambiar su tamaño:`
Al modificar el tamaño de la ventana principal, o mover la sub-ventana fuera de los límites de ella, se crea un scroll y sale ningún elemento por fuera.
[image: Ventana al cambiar su tamaño]

`Sub-ventana maximizada:`
La sub-ventana tiene la posibilidad de maximizarse y ocupar todo el espacio dentro de la ventana principal o incluso de minimizarse. Esto no es necesario para mi proyecto pero lo muestro para que se comprenda bien el funcionamiento en este caso.
[image: Sub-Ventana maximizada]

Bien por último les dejo mi código:

main.py:

```
class Fondo(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet(BACKGROUND_BLUE_GRADIENT)
        self.imagen = QPixmap(BACKGROUND_FILE)
        self.setPixmap(self.imagen)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        # CONFIGURACIONES GENERALES DE LA VENTANA
        # Título de la ventana
        self.setWindowTitle(f'Título de la ventana')
        # Ícono
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(ICON))
        # Barra de estado
        self.setStatusBar(QStatusBar(self))
        # Barra de menú
        self._barra_menu()
        # Fondo
        self.fondo = Fondo()

        # CONTENIDO DE LA VENTANA
        self.setCentralWidget(self.fondo)
        # Mostrar la ventana maximizada por defecto
        self.showMaximized()

    def _barra_menu(self): ... 
    # Acá viene muchísimo código con cada botón y sus respectivos slots y statustip, etc. que 
    # no pongo para no extender el post sin sentido
```

GenericModal.py

```
class GenericModal(QDialog):
    """
    Esta clase genera una ventana modal genérica para utilizar en las distintas apps del sistema
    """
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        # CONFIGURACIONES GENERALES DE LA VENTANA
        # Ícono
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(ICON))
        # Tamaño de la ventana
        self.resize(SCREEN_WIDHT-10, SCREEN_HEIGHT-110)
        # Posición de la ventana
        self.move(5,50)
```

Las constantes están creadas en un archivo a parte:

```
SCREEN_WIDHT = windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0)
SCREEN_HEIGHT = windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
```

caja.py

```
class VerMovimientos(GenericModal):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        # Título de la ventana
        self.setWindowTitle(f'Movimientos de caja')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de muchísima búsqueda, y tantos mas intentos fallidos, logré hacer lo que quería (sólo me falta hacer que las sub-ventanas sean modales). Así que voy a dejar acá cómo lo conseguí por si alguien tiene la misma duda:

Primero las importaciones:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QStatusBar, QMdiArea, QWidget
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap, QAction, QPalette, QColor
```

Creé la clase mdiArea que hereda de la clase QMdiArea:

```
class mdiArea(QMdiArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Establecí un fondo transparente (QColor(r,g,b,a)
        self.setBackground(QColor(0, 0, 0, 0))
        # Establecí que se creen scrollbars sólo en caso de ser necesarias
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
```

Creé la clase MainWindow que hereda de la clase QMainWindow:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Establecí una hoja de estilos donde se coloca una imagen de fondo
        # y se indica que no se repita
        self.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{background-image: url('docs/background.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat}")
        # Establecí el título de la ventana
        self.setWindowTitle(f'Título de la app')
        # Establecí un ícono para la ventana
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('docs/icono.ico'))
        # Creé una barra de estado de color blanco (ya que se creaba transparente)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(self)
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        pal = QPalette()
        pal.setColor(QPalette.Window, Qt.GlobalColor.white)
        self.statusbar.setPalette(pal)
        self.statusbar.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        # Creé una barra de menú a partir de una función
        self._barra_menu()
        # CONTENIDO DE LA VENTANA
        # Creé un objeto de la clase mdiArea y lo establecí como CentralWidget
        self.area_mdi = mdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.area_mdi)
        # Indiqué que la ventana se muestre maximizada por defecto
        self.showMaximized()

# Definí la función para crear la barra de menú (no dejo el código ya que
# extendería mucho la respuesta y no aporta nada a ésta)
def _barra_menu(self): ...
```

Para hacer que una sub-ventana se cree dentro del área MDI se debe hace de la siguiente manera:

```
# Se debe crear una sub-ventana de la clase deseada (en este ejemplo uso
# simplemente un QWidget
self.sub_window = QWidget()
# Se la establece como sub-ventana del área MDI
self.mdiArea.area_mdi.addSubWindow(self.sub_window)
# Se muestra
self.sub_window.show()
```

Creé la app, la ventana principal y la mostré:

```
if __name__ == '___main__':
    app = QApplication()
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Eso es todo, espero que le sirva a alguien...

EDIT:

Si bien no logré aún hacer que las sub-ventanas sean modales, agregué el siguiente código a la creación de éstas para evitar que se abran más de una a la vez:

```
# Chequeamos si hay una ventana activa, y si devuelve True hacemos pass
if self.area_mdi.activeSubWindow():
    pass
# Si devuelve False
else:
    # Creamos la sub-ventana con el código que coloqué antes
    self.sub_window = QWidget()
    self.area_mdi.addSubWindow(self.sub_window)
    self.sub_window.show()
```

Si bien no es lo mismo, me sirve para lo que estoy desarrollando.

Seguramente se pueda bloquear la barra de menú (o cambiarla por una dedicada para la sub-ventana) y devolverla al estado anterior al momento de cerrarla.

Saludos